# Samba4 DC, настройки DNS

Tags: samba, active-directory

День добрый. Есть парочка вопросов по Samba4 в роли DС.
Samba4 (4.3.11) установлена и настроена. Если на клиентской машине указать DNS Samba, то машина вводится в домен и все работает, соответственно, если не указывать, то получаем ошибку: "Не удалось разрешить DNS-имя контроллера домена".
В Samba используется свой внутренний DNS. В роли внешнего DNS служит Mikrotik. В static DNS прописан домен, но это не спасает. Если вместо mikrotik использовать openwrt и прописать в dnsmasq "address=/domen.loc/ip", то машины также буду заводиться в домен, даже без указания ip samba. Как это побороть?
И второй вопрос, как назначать полномочия пользователей windows в Samba4(пользователь/администратор)?

Comment: 2 вопрос снят. Был "прикручен" LAM 5.6 и стандартный admin pack

Comment: Можно увидеть /ip dns print с mikrotik?